# save radiogroup onSavedInstance

Tags: java, android, android-radiogroup, onsaveinstancestate

i have a problem with saving radiogroup status when screen rotates.
I have two independent radiogroups with 2 radiobuttons for every radiogroup.
I try to use get, `getCheckedRadioButtonId` but it doesn't work at all.

What i am doing wrong and how to save radiougroup checked radiobutton properly ?
Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

xml:

```
     <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/radio_result_group"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/textView"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/convert_to3"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textView">

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/metric_sys_result"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:padding="4dp"
                android:text="@string/metric_sys"
                android:textSize="14sp" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/imperial_sys_result"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"

                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:padding="4dp"
                android:text="@string/imperial_sys"
                android:textColorLink="@color/colorAccent"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/measurementView" />
        </RadioGroup>
<RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radio_value_gropu"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/measurementView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/convert_from5"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/measurementView">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/metric_sys_value"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:text="@string/metric_sys"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/imperial_sys_value"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"

            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:text="@string/imperial_sys"
            android:textColorLink="@color/colorAccent"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/measurementView" />
    </RadioGroup>
```

//java code

```
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.RadioGroup;
    import android.widget.Spinner;
    import android.widget.SpinnerAdapter;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import butterknife.BindView;
    import butterknife.ButterKnife;
    import butterknife.OnClick;


    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {
        protected double getEnteredValue;
        protected SpinnerAdapter checkAdapter;
        protected int pos;
   protected ArrayAdapter<String> adapter 1, adapter2, adapter3,
                adapter4;


        @BindView(R.id.unit_From_spinner)Spinner spinnerFrom;
        @BindView(R.id.unit_To_spinner)Spinner spinnertTo;
         @BindView(R.id.radio_result_group) RadioGroup resultGroup;
        @BindView(R.id.radio_value_gropu) RadioGroup valueGroup;
       @BindView(R.id.valueEditTextView) EditText valueEdit;
      @BindView(R.id.resultView) TextView resultView;
        @BindView(R.id.conver_button) Button  convertButton;

        @Override
        public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            savedInstanceState.putString("result",resultView.getText().toString());
            savedInstanceState.putString("value",valueEdit.getText().toString());
            savedInstanceState.putInt("from",spinnerFrom.getSelectedItemPosition()); // get selected item from spinner 1
            savedInstanceState.putInt("to",spinnertTo.getSelectedItemPosition());
            savedInstanceState.putInt("radGroup1", resultGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
            savedInstanceState.putInt("radGroup2", valueGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
            super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        }


            @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)  {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.unifiedlayout);
            ButterKnife.bind(this);
            convertButton.setEnabled(false);
        adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,getResources().getStringArray( R.array.adapter_1) );
    adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,getResources().getStringArray(R.array. adapter_2));
    adapter3 = new ArrayAdapter<>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,getResources().getStringArray( R.array. adapter_3) );
    adapter4 = new ArrayAdapter<>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,getResources().getStringArray(R.array. adapter_4));


        }

        @Override
        public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            resultView.setText(savedInstanceState.getString("result"));
            valueEdit.setText(savedInstanceState.getString("value"));
            spinnerFrom.setSelection(savedInstanceState.getInt("from"));
            spinnertTo.setSelection(savedInstanceState.getInt("to"));

    //?
            super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        }

    @OnClick({R.id.button1, R.id.button2,R.id.button3,R.id.button4
           } )
    public void setViewOnClickEvent(View view){
        switch(view.getId()){
            case R.id.mass_button:
                            fillSpinner(adapter1, adapter2); // fill spinner with values
                break;
            case R.id.speed_button:
                fillSpinner(adapter3,
                        adapter4);
                break;
       }
    }

protected void fillSpinner (final ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerToAdapter,
                                final ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerFromAdapter){

        valueGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup valueGroup, int checkedId) {
                pos = valueGroup.indexOfChild(findViewById(checkedId));
                switch (pos) {
                    case 0:
                        spinnerFrom.setAdapter(spinnerToAdapter);
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        spinnerFrom.setAdapter(spinnerFromAdapter);
                        break;
                }
            }
        });
        resultGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup resultGroup, int checkedId) {
                pos = resultGroup.indexOfChild(findViewById(checkedId));
                switch (pos) {
                    case 0:
                        spinnertTo.setAdapter(spinnerToAdapter);
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        spinnertTo.setAdapter(spinnerFromAdapter);
                        break;
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already save the id of the checked `RadioButton`s like this:

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    //
    // saving other values...
    //
    outState.putInt("radGroup1", resultGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
    outState.putInt("radGroup2", valueGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
    Log.d(TAG, "onSaveInstanceState: result id " + resultGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId() + ", value id = " + valueGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```

So you can retrieve the saved values either in `onCreate()` (note: only `if(savedInstanceState != null)` ) or in `onRestoreInstanceState()`. The second method will only be called if  *savedInstanceState* is not `null`.

```
private int checkedResultButtonsId;
private int checkedValueButtonsId;

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    checkedResultButtonsId = savedInstanceState.getInt("radGroup1");
    checkedValueButtonsId = savedInstanceState.getInt("radGroup2");
    Log.d(TAG, "onRestoreInstanceState: result id " + checkedResultButtonsId + ", value id = " + checkedValueButtonsId);
}
```

Normally you do not need to set the checked state of a `RadioButton` manually after a configuration change. My sample app (just plain android, no data binding) keeps the state of the `RadioButton`s automatically, so I'm not sure why you need to save the id's like you do. Your question sounds like the `RadioGroup` loses its state on rotation.

(Maybe you just do not call `super.onRestoreInstanceState()`? At least it is missing in your MainActivity code snippet )

So I tried to simulate this effect by resetting all `RadioButton`s to *unchecked* after the call to `super.onRestoreInstanceState()` and restored the state by using the saved values:

> ```
> @Override
> protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>     super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
>     resetRadioButtons(resultGroup);
>     resetRadioButtons(valueGroup);
>
>     checkedResultButtonsId = savedInstanceState.getInt("radGroup1");
>     checkedValueButtonsId = savedInstanceState.getInt("radGroup2");
>
>     // if saved values are > 0: set checked state to 'true'
>     if(checkedResultButtonsId > 0){
>         ((RadioButton)resultGroup.findViewById(checkedResultButtonsId)).setChecked(true);
>     }
>     if(checkedResultButtonsId > 0){
>         ((RadioButton)valueGroup.findViewById(checkedValueButtonsId)).setChecked(true);
>     }
> }
> ```

The result was a bit weird: the restored `RadioButton`s seemed to be stuck in an unchecked state and only recovered after checking their sibling `RadioButton`.

I guess my code snippet somehow interfered with the workings of `super.onRestoreInstanceState()`. So I moved the problematic parts to `onStart()`:

```
@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    checkedResultButtonsId = savedInstanceState.getInt("radGroup1");
    checkedValueButtonsId = savedInstanceState.getInt("radGroup2");
}
```

Note: `resetRadioButtons()` is my just way of ensuring that there is something to restore: uncheck every `RadioButton` in the `RadioGroup`.

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    resetRadioButtons(resultGroup);
    resetRadioButtons(valueGroup);

    if(checkedResultButtonsId > 0){
        ((RadioButton)resultGroup.findViewById(checkedResultButtonsId)).setChecked(true);
    }
    if(checkedResultButtonsId > 0){
        ((RadioButton)valueGroup.findViewById(checkedValueButtonsId)).setChecked(true);
    }
}
```

This worked nicely, so I hope it's helpful for you as well.

Comment: Yeah, logs looks good. 
But only now i notice that my AndroidSpinner doesn't save it's adapter in  onSaveInstanceState r and when app destroys and recreate  in onRestoreInstanceState it's just empty.
Thanks for the help!